# Linear Algebra Direct Sums and Tensor Products

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

can you please help with question 11?

> Let $T \in L(V,V).$ Extend Theorem (28.10) to prove that there exists a linear transformation $T^{(k)}$ of $\bigotimes_k(V)$ such that
>   $$
> T^{(k)}(v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k) = T(v_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes T(v_k) \quad \text{for all } v_i \in V. 
> $$
>   Prove that $\bigwedge_k (V)$ is an invariant subspace relative to $T^{(k)}$ for all $T \in L(V,V)$.

[(image of question)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfuth.jpg)

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Hello John, Welcome to Math stack Exchange. You may find these links helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . Your question, as it is written, does not meet the quality standard of the site (see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and it may be closed: you do not show your effort to solve the problem, and the problem is stated in an image (which someone may not ne able to open). You may want to edit the question to avoid your qeustion to be closed

Comment: Could you at least tell us what Theorem 28.10 says?